# Trying to submit iron-form polymer 2 - Cannot read property 'submit' of null

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, iron-form

I'm not able to submit my iron-form. At this point I just need to see the content in the console, but when trying to submit the form i'm only getting error-msg: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null. I've probably missed something obvious. I've been using the page: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-form

```
<iron-form id="sizeForm">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <paper-dropdown-menu label="Choose type" on-iron-select="_typeSelected">
                <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content">
                    <paper-item value="Sneakers">Sneakers</paper-item>
                    <paper-item value="Shoes">Shoes</paper-item>
                    <paper-item value="T-shirts">T-shirts</paper-item>
                    <paper-item value="Jeans">Jeans</paper-item>
                </paper-listbox>
            </paper-dropdown-menu>
            <add-sneakers hidden$="{{hideSneakers}}"></add-sneakers>
            <paper-button onclick="{{_submitForm}}">Accept</paper-button>
            <div class="output"></div>
        </form>
    </iron-form>

<script>
    _submitForm() {
    document.getElementById('sizeForm').submit();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<paper-button onclick="{{_submitForm}}">Accept</paper-button>
```

to

```
<paper-button on-tap="_submitForm">Accept</paper-button>
```

or

```
<button onclick="_submitForm()">Accept</button>
```

Also, it seems the [`iron-form` docs](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-form/elements/iron-form) got it wrong: `document.getElementById('sizeForm').submit()` works with a `button` but not a `paper-button`. `this.$.sizeForm.submit()` works with either. (I'll explore this more, and may submit a pull request on it.)

See [this pen](https://codepen.io/johnthad/pen/gebdNg?editors=1001) for an example.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't works for me, "Uncaught ReferenceError: _submitForm is not defined"

Comment: Ah, you are dead right. Thanks, I should have tried that before commenting. I've written a pen for it (see above) and correct my answer.

Comment: @notwaldorf has explained what I (we?) were missing from the example. See https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-form/pull/256

Comment: This is great, thanks, to both of you! Now I just need to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the id attribute to the **form** according to what you have on the javascript.

```
<form id="form_name" method="post" action="">
```

and correct it on the javascript, since the id that you are using on your example is (already) defined before.

```
document.getElementById('form_name').submit();
```

So, bottom line, you need to **add** the **id** in the **form** and correct it on the js code.